# Cannot properly add Web Reference to .net core VS project

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, web-reference

I have a .wsdl file (Fedex Address Validation) which I am using to generate a web reference class. In winforms project I can add it as a web reference simply by: Add service reference -> Advanced -> Add web reference -> and paste a link to file or browse. In .net core there is no such thing, there is WCF Web Service Reference Provider, which generates the service class from .wsdl file successfully BUT I am missing some other important data classes and methods with constructors. Interesting that, I am getting this data if am using winforms way of adding a reference, nut which does not exist in .net core project. Any solutions or mentions?

Comment: Nash, any luck on this?

Comment: @ScottDuncan Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry Jack, but I believe I gave up on that effort and went on to a 'Plan B' which did not require the .wsdl, but which is also still unfinished. If I come back to this & learn anything useful, I will post it.